# How to select td element inside table using css and specific text inside td

Tags: protractor

Lets say i have the following tbody which represents a calendar in this calendar i have many td with text inside like this :

```
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>1</td>
      ...
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      ...
     </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Lets say I want to click all the options in a particular month without clicking the options which moves to next or previous month, and I used this

```
for (var i=1;i<32;i++){

            element(by.css('body > div:nth-child(7) > div.calendar.left.single > div.calendar-table > table > tbody td')).element(by.buttonText(i)).click();
        }
```

this is selector path to the `tbody` :   `body > div:nth-child(7) > div.calendar.left.single > div.calendar-table > table > tbody td`

But `.element(by.buttonText(i)).click();` does not work I guess buttonText isnt working for `td` elements

EDITS :
Right now its working except that when iterating through second loop it gives me error : element not visible while it is visible...

Page.js

```
var Page = function() {
    var that = this;
    //ELEMENTS
    this.from = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="html"]/body/app/div/layout/div/app-tabs/div/div/div/div/app-tabs-page/app-tabs-page-content/tcmetadata/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/tc-filters/div/form[2]/div[1]/label/input'));
    this.to = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="html"]/body/app/div/layout/div/app-tabs/div/div/div/div/app-tabs-page/app-tabs-page-content/tcmetadata/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/tc-filters/div/form[2]/div[2]/label/input'));

    //EVENTS
    this.clickElements = function(els){
        els.each(function (el){
            el.click();
        });
    }
    this.clickElement = function(el){
        el.click();
    }
};
module.exports = new Page;
```

test.js:

```
var page = require('./Page');
    it('should ask any question', function() {

        for (var i=1;i<15;i++){
            page.clickElement(page.from);

            element(by.xpath('//*[@id="html"]/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody')).element(by.xpath('//td[text()='+i+']')).click();
            for (var j=i; j<15;j++){
                page.clickElement(page.to);
                browser.sleep(1000);
                element(by.xpath('//*[@id="html"]/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody')).element(by.xpath('//td[text()='+j+']')).click();
            }

        }

    });
```

The first loop works but when it goes into the second loop i get an error
"element not visible" with browser.sleep i can see its visible

Comment: Instead of doing this, I suggest, add the uniq ids to each and use `for loop` with somewhat modification in it.

Comment: yes but the calendar is rendered using Jquery plugin for calendar and adding ID to all td would be very long story

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cssContainingText` to combine a CSS selector with a text condition:

```
var calendar = element(by.css('body > div:nth-child(7) > div.calendar.left.single > div.calendar-table > table > tbody'));
for (var i = 1; i < 32; ++i) {
    calendar.element(by.cssContainingText('td', i.toString())).click();
}
```

You could also use an XPath to find the text:

```
var calendar = element(by.css('body > div:nth-child(7) > div.calendar.left.single > div.calendar-table > table > tbody'));
for (var i = 1; i < 32; ++i) {
    calendar.element(by.xpath(".//td[text()='" + i + "']")).click();
}
```

And to make it faster, I would evaluate the number within the XPath:

```
var calendar = element(by.css('body > div:nth-child(7) > div.calendar.left.single > div.calendar-table > table > tbody'));
var months = calendar.all(by.xpath(".//td[text() > 0 and text() < 32]"));
months.each(e => e.click());
```

Comment: @Georgi Antonov, the XPath from your edit should start with a dot to be relative to the previous element: `')).element(by.xpath('.//td`

Comment: so I added dot before //td to both and it worked nice but since my callendar have previous month and next month dates inside how can i add third selection method so that it wont select TD with specific class in my case I dont want to select TD element which has class 'off'